# zlib unaccessible(connection timeout ) from Ubuntu 20.4 on virtual box but accessible on windows host

Tags: networking, 20.04, virtualbox, windows, zlib

I was downloading https://zlib.net/fossils/zlib-1.2.12.tar.gz with conan c++ package manager on my ubuntu 20.4 ubuntu running on virtualbox vm, and noticed that i was constantly getting connection timeout error
`Error downloading file https://zlib.net/fossils/zlib-1.2.12.tar.gz: 'HTTPSConnectionPool(host='zlib.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /fossils/zlib-1.2.12.tar.gz (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f697b0935b0>, 'Connection to zlib.net timed out. (connect timeout=60.0)'))'` so I tried accessing the website on  mozilla and curl in the VM and realized  the website was timing out for me from the vm. I then tried accessing the website , and tried downloading on the windows 10 host and that works just fine. Iam not sure what the problem is and cant find any relatable posts online, any idea what might be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with conan trying to fetch zlib for opencv.
Windows download working, but in the VM, wget times out.
ALso tried http instead of https and -4 flag but nothing seems to help

What worked for me was downloading the archive in windows, moving it via a shared folder to the vm and unzip it into the ~/.conan/p/zlib.../s/src folder.
Be sure to unzip it, otherwise conan will think the zlib directory is corrupted and remove it.

Kind of ugly but does the trick as a workarround until someone can provide a real solution.